# Is this the correct visualization of a LinkedList?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently studying Linked List, I reviewed some question here in stackoverflow, geeksforgeeks and I just want to clear if my understanding is correct. Also I have a few questions after I show my visualization.

**Here is a simple java program to introduce a linked list**

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    public static void main (String [] args){
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.head = new Node(1);
        Node second = new Node(2);
        Node third = new Node(3);

        list.head.next = second;
        second.next = third;
    }
}

class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

**This will create a LinkedList** `(1,2,3)`

**From What I understand here are the steps for creating the LinkedList, correct me if I am wrong**

1. You have 2 class which is `class LinkedList` and `class Node`
2. Inside the `class LinkedList` I declared an object which can be used later which is `Node head;`
3. Inside the `class Node` is another declaration of an object which is `Node next;` and a constructor that will accept a data (which I created a set of nodes)
4. Going back in `class LinkedList` I instantiate an `object list` that will be container for the nodes, so it's like an object of `class Node` inside object of `class LinkedList`

**Here is my visualization:**
[image]

**My questions are:**

1. Why can't I just create the head as `Node head = new Node(1);` instead of `Node head;`
2. From what I understand object `list` is created to be a container of objects of `class Node` is that right?
3. And finally why do I have to declare `Node next;` inside the Node constructor and why do I have to set as `next = null;`?

Comment: 1. Because they were introducing the data structure probably, notice you are creating a `LinkedList` (not a `Node`); you are seeing the destination, they were showing you the start. 2. Seems to be. 3. You don't. `next = null` would be the default. You do need to declare `Node next;` - so one `Node` can point to the next. Your visualization appears to be incorrect. `1 2 3` are not in the Node constructor. Here is a [typical visualization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/gq/2013/03/Linkedlist.png) (Node would the the two boxes) (image from geekforgeek - they use ABCD not 1234).

Comment: Ow now I get why next = null; sorry silly me, almost forgot that it will be linked later with (list.head.next = second;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a new node using `Node head = new Node(1);` it's just they were introducing what a Singly Linked List look like.
2. Yes
3. Three nodes have been allocated dynamically so the default value is `next = null;` because later you will link each node with: `llist.head.next = second; second.next = third`

**Here is a full representation:**

```
     /* Start with   the empty list. */
     LinkedList2 llist = new LinkedList2(); 

     llist.head = new Node(1); 
     Node second = new Node(2); 
     Node third = new Node(3); 

     /* Three nodes have been allocated dynamically. 
       We have references to these three blocks as head,   
       second and third 

       llist.head        second              third 
          |                |                  | 
          |                |                  | 
      +----+------+     +----+------+     +----+------+ 
      | 1  | null |     | 2  | null |     |  3 | null | 
      +----+------+     +----+------+     +----+------+ */

     llist.head.next = second; // Link first node with the second node 

     /*  Now next of the first Node refers to the second.  So they 
         both are linked. 

      llist.head        second              third 
         |                |                  | 
         |                |                  | 
     +----+------+     +----+------+     +----+------+ 
     | 1  |  o-------->| 2  | null |     |  3 | null | 
     +----+------+     +----+------+     +----+------+ */

     second.next = third; // Link second node with the third node 

     /*  Now next of the second Node refers to third.  So all three 
         nodes are linked. 

      llist.head        second              third 
         |                |                  | 
         |                |                  | 
     +----+------+     +----+------+     +----+------+ 
     | 1  |  o-------->| 2  |  o-------->|  3 | null | 
     +----+------+     +----+------+     +----+------+ */
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You seem to be confusing the idea of *creating* the head (`new Node(1)`), assigning it (the `=` operator), and declaring it (`Node head;`). Your class definition only needs this instance variable to be declared, with the constructor handling the creation and assignment of this object.
2. The purpose of the `Node` class is to contain both the value and a link to the next object. Therefore, there is no reason to treat your `LinkedList` class as a container for all `Node` objects in that list as you might for other list types.
3. `next = null;` is unnecessary, since `null` is the default value of an instance variable.

Comment: I'm getting confused in this line llist.head = new Node(1); why should I use the the LinkedList object? isn't it to be the container of all the Node objects?

Comment: In your `main()` method, you assign `new Node(1)` to the instance variable `head` because that's the only node that your `LinkedList` needs a reference to. References to other nodes are all held in the preceding node, so there's no need for `LinkedList` to know about them.